# PayPal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Invalid token

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I'm trying to create recurring payment using SOAP API , i did the following steps as mentioned in PayPal API manual :

1- Call "set express checkout" API.
2- Get token and redirect the buyer to PayPal site.
3- After user finished he will redirected to my response page.
4- Call "do express checkout" API.
5- Call "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" API.

my call SOAP structure:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:urn1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <urn:RequesterCredentials>
      <urn1:Credentials>
        <urn1:Username>'+un+'</urn1:Username>
        <urn1:Password>'+pw+'</urn1:Password>
        <urn1:Signature>'+sig+'</urn1:Signature>
      </urn1:Credentials>
    </urn:RequesterCredentials>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>
      <urn:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
        <urn1:Version>'+version+'</urn1:Version>
        <urn1:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
          <urn1:Token>'+token+'</urn1:Token>
          <urn1:RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails>
            <urn1:SubscriberName>'+FirstName+' '+LastName+'</urn1:SubscriberName>
            <urn1:BillingStartDate>'+strCurrentDate+'</urn1:BillingStartDate>
          </urn1:RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails>
          <urn1:ScheduleDetails>
            <urn1:Description>'+BillingAgreementDescription+'</urn1:Description>
            <urn1:PaymentPeriod>
              <urn1:BillingPeriod>'+billingPeriod+'</urn1:BillingPeriod>
              <urn1:BillingFrequency>'+billingFrequency+'</urn1:BillingFrequency>
              <urn1:Amount currencyID="'+UsedCurrency+'">'+amount+'</urn1:Amount>
            </urn1:PaymentPeriod>
          </urn1:ScheduleDetails>
        </urn1:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails>
      </urn:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest>
    </urn:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem with SOAP body structure it should be like :

```
  string doExpressCheckout = '';
    doExpressCheckout += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:urn1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
    doExpressCheckout += '<soapenv:Header>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn:RequesterCredentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Credentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Username>'+un+'</urn1:Username>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Password>'+pw+'</urn1:Password>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Signature>'+sig+'</urn1:Signature>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn1:Credentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn:RequesterCredentials>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</soapenv:Header>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<soapenv:Body>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Version>'+version+'</urn1:Version>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:Token>'+token+'</urn1:Token>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:PayerID>'+payerID+'</urn1:PayerID>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:PaymentDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '<urn1:OrderTotal currencyID="'+UsedCurrency+'">'+amount+'</urn1:OrderTotal>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn1:PaymentDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn1:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</urn:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</soapenv:Body>';
    doExpressCheckout += '</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this is happening to people it's because you didn't include the billing agreement parameters in your SetExpressCheckout request.  Therefore, the token you get back is indeed invalid for use with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Here's an [old sample set of calls](http://angelleye.com/temp/sample-set.php) I put together to answer this very question for people.  It's using NVP instead of SOAP, but you can see that it's including the BILLINGTYPE and BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION parameters in the SEC request.  Make sure you're including those in your SEC request accordingly.